# Can an evolutionary algorithm adapt to a changing environment?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms

[From this SE question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2067/will-ai-be-able-to-adapt):

> Will be AI able to adapt, to different environments and changes.

This is my attempt at interpreting that question.

Evolutionary algorithms are useful for solving optimization problems...by measuring the "fitness" of various probable solutions and then  of an algorithm through the process of natural selection.

Suppose, the "fitness calculation"/"environment" is changed in mid-training (as could easily happen in real-life scenarios where people may desire different solutions at different times). Would evolutionary algorithms be able to respond effectively to this change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core question to whether or not an AI is adaptable or not is whether or not it supports [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning). That doesn't mean using the Internet to learn things; that means continuing to accept training data during the functioning of the system.

This is (mostly) independent of the underlying architecture; in evolutionary approaches one can continue to breed generations with a shifting fitness function or with neural networks one can continue to backpropagate errors, and so on with other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I think Matthew Graves' answer is the strictly correct one. But I also think this question may be hinting at a larger question in general. What is the minimal algorithmic complexity required for a machine of one particular set of functions to mutate into some other machine of some other particular set of functions?

The answer is: potentially *infinite* algorithmic complexity. Without knowing a priori how many steps it will take to mutate into a thing that can solve some black-box problem, there is no way to determine if and when the AI will be able to mutate into that thing.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is with respect to game theory perspective, **Replicator Dynamics** is one of core concept of evolutionary game theory algorithm which means rate of adaptation with respect to rate of change in population. Whenever there is change in the system replicator dynamics will help to adapt with the change with respect to utility function.

[Replicator Dynamics Equation](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial%20x%5Cleft%20(%20t%20%5Cright%20)%7D%7B%5Cpartial%20t%7D%20%3D%20x%0A%0A%5Cleft%20(%20%20t%5Cright%20)%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%0AU_%7BA%7D%5Cleft%20(%20t%20%5Cright%20)%20-%20%5Cdot%7BU%5Cleft%20(%20t%20%5Cright%20)%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%0A%0A)

For Better Understanding go through this link: [Evolutionary Algorithm Pdf](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~miekisz/cime.pdf)

Hope this will be helpful.